# Why does Neo4j index query return no results on linux while the same query returns results on macOS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, lucene, neo4j, centos6

I have a Rails application using Jruby and embedding a neo4j database. While developing under MacOS 10.8.5, using Jruby 1.7.4 (JDK 1.7.0), I issued an index query to retrieve a node having key-value pairs "name: bento && type: services", after verifying through the ActiveRecord that the node does exist.

When I issued the same ran the same sequence on CentOS 6.4, the index query returns no results.

My question is, why isn't my index query working on CentOS 6.4, while it works on MacOS 10.8.5?

Here is the console session transcript for MacOS, followed by the one for CentOS:

====================================================

```
[On MacOS 10.8.5, using Jruby 1.7.4 (JDK 1.7.0), using Neo4j Community 1.9.1]

irb(main):001:0> # verify that node with name: bento && type: services exists

irb(main):002:0> Vertex.all.select{|v| v.name == "bento" && v.type=="services"}[0].name
=> "bento"
irb(main):003:0> Vertex.all.select{|v| v.name == "bento" && v.type=="services"}[0].type
=> "services"

irb(main):004:0> # Attempt to retrieve that same node using Neo4j Lucene Index Manager

irb(main):005:0> thisgraph =  Neo4j.db.graph
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jKernel::EmbeddedGraphDatabase:0x662a6d5b>
irb(main):006:0> index_manager = thisgraph.index
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jKernel::IndexManagerImpl:0x77a89d44>
irb(main):007:0> node_exact_index_manager = index_manager.for_nodes("Node_Exact")
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jIndexImplLucene::NodeIndex:0xb55bed2>
irb(main):008:0> service = node_exact_index_manager.query("name: bento && type: services").getSingle()
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jKernelImplCore::NodeProxy:0x2666829a>
irb(main):009:0> service[:name]
=> "bento"
irb(main):010:0> service[:type]
=> "services"

===========================
[On CentOS 6.4, using Jruby 1.7.4 (JDK 1.7.0), using Neo4j Community 1.9.1 ]
# verify that node with name: bento && type: services exists
irb(main):008:0> Vertex.all.select{|v| v.name == "bento" && v.type=="services"}[0].name
=> "bento"
irb(main):009:0> Vertex.all.select{|v| v.name == "bento" && v.type=="services"}[0].type
=> "services"

# Attempt to retrieve that same node using Neo4j Lucene Index Manager

irb(main):011:0> thisgraph =  Neo4j.db.graph
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jKernel::EmbeddedGraphDatabase:0x1acf245f>
irb(main):012:0> index_manager = thisgraph.index
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jKernel::IndexManagerImpl:0x55fcebbe>
irb(main):013:0> node_exact_index_manager = index_manager.for_nodes("Node_Exact")
=> #<Java::OrgNeo4jIndexImplLucene::NodeIndex:0x20bcb45a>
irb(main):014:0> service = node_exact_index_manager.query("name: bento && type: services").getSingle()
=> nil
```

=========================

The two databases and indexes, on MacOS and on CentOS, are identical. For good measure, I viewed both indexes (the one on MacOS and the one on CentOS) using Luke and verified that the node I was querying for can indeed be retrieved using the query string "name: bento && type: services".

[ It was just verified that we are seeing the same behavior on RedHat as on CentOS ]

I would appreciate any answers as to why the query on CentOS is yielding no results. Thank you.

Comment: (I found the problem; posting as a comment to get around the 8-hour waiting period requirement before posting answer): Index is Node_exact, not Node_Exact, it worked on OSX because it is apparently case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

The statement to obtain the node index is using "Node_Exact" as the index name parameter.

```
node_exact_index_manager = index_manager.for_nodes("Node_Exact")
```

The actual index is named Node_exact, with a lower case e. OsX is apparently treating the index name as case-insensitive, while this is not the case for Linux (both the CentOS and RedHat flavors).

The results showed up correctly once the index name parameter was corrected to "Node_exact".

```
node_exact_index_manager = index_manager.for_nodes("Node_exact")
```